# Is is possible to configure a pre-execution script in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

When I'm running python code in vscode I just hit F5 in the current file and it runs. But the code requires some environment variables to exist and it's easy to forget setting those, making the code fail.

Is it possible to configure a script to run before execution/debugging of the main file? Something like a pre-execution script? That way I could run a script that sets the environment variables before execution of the main python code.

Comment: There should be no way to set environment variables by executing scripts before starting debugging, but VSCode provides a method to directly define environment variables [environment-variable-definitions-file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file)

Comment: @alex That sounds like a good fit for my problem. Thanks!